# approximation algorithm for Travelling Salesman Problem: with a different inequality and not triangle inequality

Tags: algorithm-analysis, approximation, traveling-salesman

I have the following question for the travelling salesman problem:

The TSP algorithm is to find a complete hamilton cycle with minimum cost in a weighted graph **G**. Instead of the traingle inequality, the weight function satisfies the following inequality:

```
cost(u,w) < cost(u,v) + 2 x cost(v,w)
```

Find the approximation ratio if we use the following approximation algorithm:

```
1. Select any vertex as root vertex
2. Compute a minimum spanning tree T from graph G
3. Let L be the list of vertices visited in a preorder tree walk of T
4. return the hamilton cycle H that visits the vertices in the order L
```

**My work so far**

I figured out that it is 2-approximation if it is the triangle inequality, since going directly from one vertex to another has a cost no greater than going to a vertex in between these two vertices, so `cost(H)` is not greater than the cost of the preorder tree walk and therefore no greater than twice the cost of the optimal tour.

However, inequality `cost(u,w) < cost(u,v) + 2 x cost(v,w)` would make it different than triangle inequality that going directly `from u to w` could result in higher cost than `from u to v to w` (unless `cost(v,w)=0`). I think the worst case is extra cost of `cost(u,v) + 2 x cost(v,w) - (cost(u,v) + cost(v,w))= cost(v,w)`

Any advice on this? I need to find the approximation ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Review the standard proof that it's a 2-approximation if the weight function satisfies the triangle inequality.  That suggests a way to upper-bound the total length of the Hamilton cycle $H$ returned by the algorithm.

Adjust that reasoning.  For starters, assume that every edge in $H$ is a "shortcut edge" $(u,w)$ that was taken by skipping a single vertex $v$.  What could you conclude about the cost of $H$, compared to the cost of $T$?  If you do a little bit of algebra you should be able to obtain an expression.

Now generalize to arbitrary $H$.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. A spanning tree has (n-1) edges. The cost of full walk W is twice the cost of T. As calculated from before, the extra cost from this inequality is cost(v,w) for each shortcut. Therefore, the cost of H = (the cost of W) + (n-1)cost(v,w). Comparing the cost of H to the cost of T, that makes the cost of H = 2 x (the cost of T) + (n-1)cost(v,w), and since the cost of T is less than or equal to the cost of the optimal tour, that means the cost of H is less than or equal to 2 x (the cost of the optimal tour) + (n-1)cost(v,w)

Comment: so that makes it a (2+(n-1)cost(v,w)) approximation